# D traits - List of integral data members

Tags: d, type-traits, ctfe

I am trying to use the following code to get a list of integral data members from class:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

class D
{
    static string[] integralMembers = getIntegralMembers();

    static string[] getIntegralMembers()
    {
        auto allMembers = __traits(allMembers, D);

        string[] tmp = new string[allMembers.length];
        int ct = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i != allMembers.length; ++i) {
            bool isInteg = __traits(isIntegral, __traits(getMember, D, allMembers[i]));
            if(isInteg) {
                tmp[ct++] = allMembers[i];
            }
        }

        string[] ret = new string[ct];

        for(int i = 0; i != ct; ++i) {
            ret[i] = tmp[i];
        }

        return ret;
    }

    int a;
    this() { }
    ~this() { }
}

void main()
{
    auto integralMembers = D.integralMembers;

    foreach(mem; integralMembers)
    {
        writeln(mem);
    }
}
```

But, compilation is failing with these errors:

```
main.d(17): Error: variable i cannot be read at compile time
main.d(17): Error: expression expected as second argument of __traits getMember
main.d(19): Error: variable i cannot be read at compile time
main.d(7):        called from here: getIntegralMembers()
```

How do I make this code compile?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Even though the function will only run during compilation within that program, it must still be compilable as a function that can run at runtime.

1. You need to declare `allMembers` as a manifest constant:

   ```
   enum allMembers = __traits(allMembers, D);
   ```

   `allMembers` is a tuple. If you use `auto`, it will be saved as a tuple of strings on the "stack", becoming a runtime value, thus inaccessible to compile-time evaluation for `__traits`.
2. You need to use `foreach` instead of `for`. `foreach` over a tuple is special in that it will unroll statically, thus the index (and value) will be accessible to `__traits`.

Fixed program:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

class D
{
    static string[] integralMembers = getIntegralMembers();

    static string[] getIntegralMembers()
    {
        enum allMembers = __traits(allMembers, D);

        string[] tmp = new string[allMembers.length];
        int ct = 0;

        foreach(i, member; allMembers) {
            bool isInteg = __traits(isIntegral, __traits(getMember, D, member));
            if(isInteg) {
                tmp[ct++] = allMembers[i];
            }
        }

        string[] ret = new string[ct];

        for(int i = 0; i != ct; ++i) {
            ret[i] = tmp[i];
        }

        return ret;
    }

    int a;
    this() { }
    ~this() { }
}

void main()
{
    auto integralMembers = D.integralMembers;

    foreach(mem; integralMembers)
    {
        writeln(mem);
    }
}
```